# CSS is overriding arrow function in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component in which I need to change the color of the p tag every time the page refreshes. I defined the arrow function to generate a random color. Then I used the style attribute to give it a color generated by function. However, when I run and inspect the element I see the blue color in the module.css file which I already removed from the file.

arrow function to generate random color

```
const getDifferentColors = () => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},0.8)`;
};
```

p tag which I am trying to change

```
 <p className={styles["contributor-title"]} style={{color:`${getDifferentColors()}`}}>Location of Contributors</p>
```

and module.css code for the class

```
.contributor-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: "Mefika", sans-serif;
    /* color: blue; */
}
```

And I am attaching photo of inspect element:
[image]

Comment: What does your HTML output look like? I'd assume there's a syntax issue in how you're specifying the `style` attribute

Comment: ``` <>
    <p className={styles["contributor-title"]} style={{color: getDifferentColors()}}>Location of Contributors</p>
    <MapContainer
      center={[0, 0]}
      zoom={2}
      style={{ height: '500px', width: '100%' }}
      
    />
 </>
```

these are the only lines i have

Comment: It is working for another component. I am not able to know where exactly the problem is. Even if I comment out the color in module.css; it still shows up when I run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

try writing

```
import React from 'react';
import './module.css';

const getDifferentColors = () => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},0.8)`;
};

export default function App() {
  let className = 'contributor-title';
  return (
    <div>
      <p className={className} style={{ color: `${getDifferentColors()}` }}>
        Location of Contributors
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it worked for me

Comment: I resolved it. Thanks for your suggestion. I did make some mistakes in reviewing the code.

Answer (score -1):

Either you have some mistake where your inlined color function is called or the specificity of the other selector is too high which I kinda doubt.

Anyways try checking what your html looks and also try using a !important.

Comment: I resolved it. Thanks for your suggestion.